# GTK, child parent, shared memories and

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I'm really new to GTK and been trying to figure it. What I have now is

```
Widgets *w;               // shared mem
struct mystruct *user;    // shared mem
....
pid = fork();
.....
if(pid == 0) {
    while(1){
        get_events(user);
        parse_events(user);
        // can I write to Widgets *w and the changes happen in the
        // parent process that is running the gtkmainloop
        write_to_textview("child", w);
    }
} else {
    ......
    write_to_textview("parent", w);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

user is a shared struct between the parent, child 'and others' this struct contains data that I want to preview in the parent process in a GtkTextView as soon as they're available
which I'm not sure how to do it. It's not possible to use a something like this in the parent

```
while(1) {
     is_available_data(user);
}
```

that will check if the data is available and then write the data to the GtkTextView. This is not possible because of the gtk main loop. There must be another way in this senario so I can be able to watch for a user->events (char *) as soon as it's updated or available it should be printed again (user is shm and events is shm too) but how can I tell gtk to loop. GtkThreads ?

Is there an easy way using shm to write to a widget from the child process (where the widget is running in the parent process) ?

I'm sure there are other ways easier than what I'm trying to do.

Edit 1:

I can see the data produced/changed/added from the Child process in the struct and see it with no problems in the Parent process (shm). All I want to do is update the TextView as soon as the data changes which I belive I need a while loop that have to check and update, but that can't happen since gtkmainloop is blocking. I need ideas or a way to do it. I've spent sometime trying to figure out gtk related calls to help me but couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "shared mem"? Do you just mean that you set up the pointers et cetera before calling `fork()`, so that each process has access to the same data? If so, then that does *not* work for actually changing the data and have all processes see the change. This is because `fork()` creates a *process*, and processes have separate address spaces. In Linux, the data is set up to be "copied on write", so it looks like the data is truly shared, but as soon as a process does a change to the data, it gets its own copy.

To share data using *real* shared memory, you need to use a call such as `shmget()`, but I don't think you can convince GTK+ to create its widgets only in true shared memory.

The solution is to use *threads*, and be Very Careful to avoid doing multiple accesses, i.e. [don't call GTK+ from several different threads](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness).

Comment: Unwind thank you for the replay. By shared memory I mean I've used XSI shared memory segments setting the pointers to point to a memory that can be accessed from the parent/child or any other process (sys/shm.h). Yes I believe my only way now to access the data and effect changes and other things is by either using threads or trying to build my gtk/window/widgets at the shared memory level. I believe threads are the easier way to go at this point. "Was going to upvote you but my reputation is below 15, thanks again!"